# Is a non-negotiable salary offer actually non-negotiable for internship?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I am a talented software engineer student with background in finance. I have been offered several positions at company X with different independent teams and I have also been equally successful interviewing at dozen of other companies.

I picked company X because they have a reputable business ethics in the engineering field, but with the assumption that the salary will be competitive (co-op prohibit me to discuss salaries at interviews) and that my time will be valued there, but their third party talent recruitment company later tells me that they do not negotiate on salary based on individual talents (same salary for all co-op students per level).

The salary they offered me is less than advertised on Glassdoor, and 40% less than my previous part-time position.

I know the managers at company X want my skills and see potentials in me: they ranked me first in all positions I applied after interviewing perhaps hundreds of candidates and they are having a hard time finding candidates for the positions I did not chose. They invested time and energy into securing me over dozens of other offers.

Is there a way to negotiate around a non-negotiable position from a recruitment agency?

Comment: Can you apply to the company directly? Or does it have to be through the recruitment agency? Sometimes if you can apply directly you might have more negotiating power.

Comment: What the recruiter said is a joke, just state what you want.  (That being said, why should interns be paid anything? It's either priceless experience (in which case ignore the $) or it's a rubbish position (in which case leave!))  Purely one man's opinion: perhaps you should have nothing to do with them, if that's their attitude, even if expressed through their recruiter company.

Comment: In my experience, internship salaries are even *less* negotiable than standard positions. Every level is budgeted at a certain amount, and only so many interns at each level are budgeted for.

Comment: That's a reasonable point, @DavidK - arguably, it's a bit different in the sort of companies at hand.

Comment: @Fattie Different how? And what sort of companies are you referring to?

Comment: junk-bond traders, quants, financial software - they are often incredibly aggressive with salaries and the folks who work there are incredibly aggressive with salaries.

Comment: which brings to an interesting point, OP.  just get your foot in the door, and in a few months, if you're so hot, hit them up for more money.  that would be a more typical move in your industry, than, fussing about a coupe of dollars ahead of time - you know?  Food for thought.

Comment: Have you turned down the other companies? Negotiating power comes from your ability to walk away. @Fattie Never seen that work. People ask on wp.se all the time things like "I'm 3 month into a job, how do I get a pay rise". The answer is always that they have no negotiation leverage at that point, and should wait or quit.

Comment: @Fattie 1. Where on earth are you getting "junk-bond traders" and quants? OP said they are applying to an engineering firm. 2. There you go again making only strong assertions and broad generalizations about something you are not very familiar with.

Comment: You'd better ask your school about this. You mentioned that you're not allowed to discuss salary because it's a co-op position. If that restriction is coming from the school, there may not be much you can do. You could also ask about entering at a higher co-op level based on previous employment.

Comment: Also, if the recruiter is connected to the school, there may be agreements in place that the recruiters only get so much per placement, so they have no reason to go above-and-beyond.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful responses! They brought very interesting views! I will likely request a higher co-op level salary based on previous employment; and I am not in the mood to give into the third party non-negotiation request unless it comes from company X itself.

Comment: hi @DavidK - totally unsure what you're referring to?  Look at the NAME of the OP.  what's the confusion?

Comment: "and I am not in the mood to give into the third party non-negotiation request unless it comes from company X itself"  I'm not sure you're view really captures the situation, @quant_trader101.  A stock phrase from "recruiters" is "that is the salary limit".  Just ignore it and state what you feel you want.  Be aware that salary negotiation means you can walk away.

Comment: @Fattie interns who are doing valuable work (which is the case at the engineering firm I work for) absolutely should be paid based on the value they provide. That value will be less than a senior engineer, but it is not zero.

Comment: if your experienced why are you applying for internships

Answer (score 8):

Everything is negotiable - it all depends on your leverage.

Are you willing to walk out of the table if they don't improve their offer? If so, then you have enough leverage: Just turn down their offer and explain them the reason (the offer is not competitive). That leaves them enough space to either improve it, or forget about you and go for another candidate.

Just be mindful of the risks: They can always tell you no, and then you would may need to look for a different company. But if that is fine for you, then, by all means, do not let the recruitment agency stop you. Their client is the company X, you are just their resource.

Comment: All quite true.

Comment: Yeah, we basically answered the same at same time :D

Comment: it's because we're both so clever dude

Answer (score 1):

I guess the literal answer to your question

> Is there a way to negotiate around a non-negotiable position from a recruitment agency?

is straightforward.  State:

> "I would want $X for the position."

Understand that "negotiating salary" - in any context whatsoever - simply shares an identity with "you can walk away".

If you can't walk away, you can't negotiate. (At all, in any way.)

If you can walk away, use the language "I would want $X for the position."

(Regarding the fact that the recruiter said sentences like "they don't negotiate", just treat it as an interesting set of sounds  :)  )

The only tip you need on the language per se, "I would want $X for the position," is that you never ever, in any way, explain yourself, add reasons, "argument" or anything else.  Just state what you want.  If you don't get it, walk away. Be super polite and "minimalist" as it were.  Be very mentally prepared that when/if the recruiter comes back to you with "Sorry, they wouldn't go for it" the response has to be at hand for you, something like "Understood! Thanks for your involvement, cheers".

Comment: "I want X" is in my experience rarely effective. It comes across as inflexible and rude. Your chances of success are  much better if you can provide a data based rationale and good argument.

Comment: I strongly urge being "overly polite", @Hilmar.  But note that anything one says **to a recruitment company, per se** is, literally, irrelevant, They simply **don't pass it on**: it is a complete waste of breath (or, ascii characters!!)  They recruiter will type a sentence with four words "John Smith wants $X". If you carefully and laboriously express why, etc, to a *recruiter*, it just literally achieves nothing; it's a complete waste.  Maybe you were thinking in the case of directly talking to the company in question.